# Facebook News Feed Not return all post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I am getting facebook news feed data from facebook home api, but when I am comparing it with my facebook account and data return from api it was different, there are few post missing in API return data.

So what could be the cause for this? If is there any permission issue then please suggest what kind of permission do I need to provide?

If there are any kind of data is not visible in news feed then also I need details about what kind of data is not supported by facebook home API.

Your answer will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/: _“Note: /me/home retrieves an outdated view of the News Feed. This is currently a known issue and we don't have any near term plans to bring them back up into parity.”_

Answer (score 0):

Some posts may be private (for example, you posted something, and made it visible to your friends only), and the API will get only public posts.

Visit your facebook feed and check privacy settings for posts that you don't see.